# Сохранение картинки в Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Я загружаю картинку с компьютера в программу, она открывается на виджете в lable_1. Делаю над ней всякие преобразования, которые отображаются в lable_2. После этого я хочу сохранить изменённое изображение на компьютер. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это (сохранение преобразованной картинки) можно сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Получить объект картинки из [QLabel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html)
2. Составить список поддерживаемых фильтров (опционально)
3. Вызвать диалог для выбора пути сохраняемого файла с помощью [QFileDialog::getSaveFileName](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getSaveFileName)
4. Сохранить

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/ImageConvertation/blob/master/UImageConvertationForm.cpp#L131)

```
QString filters;
foreach(QByteArray byte, QImageWriter::supportedImageFormats())
{
    QString format = byte;
    filters += QString("%1 (%2)\n")
               .arg(format.toUpper())
               .arg("*." + format);
}

QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Save as..."), "img.png", filters);
if (fileName.isEmpty() || fileName.isNull())
    return;

ui->labelImage->pixmap()->save(fileName);
```